# How do you specify permissionID in Google Drive API v3?

Tags: google-drive-api

I understand that v3 narrows the data returned from the API, which makes sense. I’m using v2 and a fileId and get a large amount of data.

I believe you have to specify permissionId in v3 to get anything beyond a basic return.

But I don’t understand what permissionId really is - I initially thought it would just be a key/value sort of thing. Specify “owner.emailAddress” in your call and get that value back for a specific fileId. But I don’t think that is the case...but I haven’t found a decent, entry-level description, perhaps because it is assumed knowledge.

If I wanted to get a document owner’s email with v3, what URL would I use in my Get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to retrieve the e-mail of document owner using Drive API v3, you can use the following request.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/### file ID ###?fields=owners%2FemailAddress
```

`owners%2FemailAddress` was URL encoded from `owners/emailAddress`.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Many thanks....

I guess it would have killed someone at Google to put that little wrinkle in the documentation (prominently). What good is pages and pages of documentation if they leave out the bleedin' syntax for making the call.

Works like a charm.

Comment: @11teenth Welcome. I'm glad your problem was solved. Thank you, too.